# Как работают виртуальные функции в c#?

Tags: c#, clr

Есть ли вообще понятие таблицы виртуальных функций в шарпе? Допустим есть иерархия классов, в классе на вершине иерархии виртуальный метод, который переопределяется в child классах. Методы с середины иерархии с меткой override заносятся в таблицу виртуальных функций? Также интересует заносится ли метод из последнего класса в иерархии?

И наконец, читаю книгу "Clr via c#", до конца не могу понять, сказано, что для структур используется call для вызова функций, т. к. это значимый тип, но структуры также неявно наследуются от System.Object и могут оверрайдить методы, так вот, вопрос, для этих методов используется call или callvirt? Также интересует, когда используется call для вызова виртуальных функций и как работает таблица виртуальных функций для структур, т.к. методы оверрайдятся.

Заранее спасибо за ответы

Answer (score 3):

> Есть ли вообще понятие таблицы виртуальных функций в шарпе? Допустим есть иерархия классов, в классе на вершине иерархии виртуальный метод, который переопределяется в child классах. Методы с середины иерархии с меткой override заносятся в таблицу виртуальных функций?

Не столько "виртуальных", сколько просто таблица функций (методов). Каждый тип имеет таблицу методов, которая хранит указатели на дескрипторы всех методов этого класса, как виртуальных, так обычных. В таблицу каждого типа заносится указатель либо на реализацию в этом типе, если это собственный или переопределенный виртуальный метод, либо на одну из реализаций выше по иерархии, если он унаследован. Естественно, каждая реализация будет в какой-то таблице, иначе как ее можно было бы вызвать?

Информацию о структуре таблицы методов можно посмотреть здесь: [.NET Framework Internals: How the CLR Creates Runtime Objects](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2005/may/net-framework-internals-how-the-clr-creates-runtime-objects) - хоть статья и старая, идеи в основном не изменились.

> сказано, что для структур используется call для вызова функций, т. к.
>   это значимый тип, но структуры также неявно наследуются от
>   System.Object и могут оверрайдить методы, так вот, вопрос, для этих
>   методов используется call или callvirt? Также интересует, когда
>   используется call для вызова виртуальных функций и как работает
>   таблица виртуальных функций для структур, т.к. методы оверрайдятся

[call](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.call) используется для вызова статического метода, либо для вызова метода экземпляра через раннее связывание (метод известен на этапе компиляции). Метод может быть как виртуальным, так и обычным, и принадлежать как структуре, так и классу. Но если вызвать виртуальный метод через `call`, virtual dispatch на деле не происходит, т.е. вызов вырождается в невиртуальный.

[callvirt](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.callvirt) используется для вызова методов экземпляра через позднее связывание (метод определяется реальным типом объекта во время выполнения). Метод может быть как виртуальным, так и обычным, и принадлежать как структуре, так и классу. Но для обычного метода позднее связывание, конечно, вырождается в ранее, так как выбирать CLR не из чего (у всех наследников реализация одна и та же).

На практике, компилятор C# генерирует `callvirt` для вызовов всех виртуальных методов и вызовов обычных методов на классах (последнее связано, насколько я знаю, с лучшей диагностикой вызовов по null-ссылкам). `call` он генерирует для вызовов статических методов и вызовов обычных методов на структурах.

Следует понимать, что тут много тонкостей, все из которых невозможно описать в рамках ответа. Например, метод, реализующий интерфейс, с точки зрения CLR будет всегда виртуальным, даже если мы об этом не просили, т.е. не пометили его `virtual` в C#. Кроме того, чтобы `callvirt` работал со структурами, используется специальный префикс [constrained](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.constrained). Полную информацию о внутренней механике CLR и структуре IL-кода можно посмотреть в спецификации [ECMA-335 Common Language Infrastructure](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm).