# Как происходит вызов сокрытого метода под капотом?

Tags: c#, методы

Я знаю, как происходит вызов виртуальных метод под капотом, но ни у Голдштейна, ни у Рихтера я не нашёл инфу о том, как происходит вызов сокрытого метода. Так как это всё-таки происходит? Help me please.
То есть как происходит вызов этого метода:

```
class A
{
 public void DoSmth()
 {

 }
}
class B : A
{
 public new void DoSmth()
 {

 }
}
class Program
{
 public static void Main()
 {
  A a = new B();
  a.DoSmth();
 }
}
```

Comment: перекрытый метод, видимо

Comment: [Полиморфизм в C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/polymorphism)

Comment: Дело в том, что перекрытый метод на уровне метаданных не сильно отличается от обычного. Это просто новый слот в таблице методов, лишь имя метода дублируется с тем, кто его перекрывает. Вот здесь есть кое-какая информация по методам в целом: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1075141/240512

Answer (score 1):

Скрытые открытые виртуальные это всё наши абстрактные понимания сущности. На уровне вызова все определено идёт вызов того или иного метода, а которого именно определено во время компиляции/интерпретации.

Ответ на ваш вопрос можно почитать
[Тут](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.42.php)

Идея сокрытия проста. С помощью new вы определяете новый метод соответственно каждый класс вызовет свою ф-ю

Comment: Это я знаю, но как это происходит под капотом?

Comment: Что вы хотите увидит там? Я говорю что это разные методы и у каждого свой. Компилятор решает который вызвать. Решает глядя на таблицу методов. У каждого класса она своя.

Comment: Если метод виртуальный то он смотрел бы на таблицу виртуальных методов. А в данном случае это разные методы хоть и название одинаковое.

Answer (score 1):

Вызов "сокрытого" метода производится, исходя из объявленного типа переменной, от которой этот метод вызывается. Определяется, какой метод вызывать, на этапе компиляции.

В Вашем примере: тип переменной `a` - `A`. Значит, вызовется метод `A.DoSmth`.

Comment: Это я знаю, но как это происходит под капотом?

Comment: @DenisBredun Кхм, кхм. Под капотом компилятор смотрит на тип переменной и думает: а здесь мы будем вызывать вот этот метод.